# How do I copy certain rows from a csv file into a new file using C#?

Tags: c#, csv

I am using C# to make a small application that automates some manual processes. I have a CSV file, I must search the second column (which has the name "Status"), if the status is "clear" then I do not need this row, else I need to copy this row into another file and save the aggregated file. Additionally, I would also like to know how to delete (automatically) certain columns of a csv file in c#. Here is what I have thus far: (The first button is "Show Original" while the second is "Alter and Save"

```
namespace AppExcel
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private static List<string[]> ReadAndParseData(string path, char separator )
    {
        var parsedData = new List<string[]>();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] row = line.Split(separator);
                string[] column = line.Split('\n');
                parsedData.Add(row);
            }

        }
        return parsedData;
    }

    private void DrawGridView(List<string[]> parsedData)
    {

        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 47;
        for (int i = 0; i < 47; i++)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(parsedData[0][i]);
            sb.Replace('_', ' ');
            sb.Replace("\"", "");
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name = sb.ToString();


        }

        foreach (string[] row in parsedData)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

        }

        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[0]);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string[]> parsedData = ReadAndParseData(@"C:/Export Data.csv", ',');


        DrawGridView(parsedData);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string[]> parsedData = ReadAndParseData(@"C:/Export Data.csv", ',');
        foreach (string[] row in parsedData)
        {
            if (row != parsedData[0])
            { 
              // What to insert here??

            }
        }

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do (if your file is not really huge : in that case you'll have to work with a streamreader)

```
var retainedLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/Export Data.csv")
                    .Skip(1) // if you have an header in your file and don't want it
                    .Where(x => x.Split(',')[1] != "clear");//don't take the lines with "clear" in second column
```

if you wanna keep the first line (headers), you may do

```
var retainedLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/Export Data.csv")
                        .Where((x, i) => i == 0 || x.Split(',')[1] != "clear");//i is the index, so the first line will have i == 0
```

then save to another file

```
File.WriteAllLines(<targetPath>, retainedLines);
```

if you wanna remove lines in the same file, your targetPath must just be the existing one...

Answer (score 1):

One liner to read file, go over lines, split into columns, check for Clear, and then write output.

```
File.WriteAllLines(outPath, 
                File
                .ReadAllLines(inPath)
                .Where(line => !line.Split(seperator)[colNum].Equals("clear")));
```